# Script or way of creating many empty folders?

Tags: shell

I store a lot of my music and some movies on my external hard drive so I can go upstairs and play them on my PS3. Not all of it is appropriate for her age group and so I am trying to devise a way to prevent her from viewing or listening to it so my parents don't yell at me. I would just encrypt it, but the PS3 does not support encryption and is a pain to decrypt a one time encryption every time I want to use it (if such a thing exists). So I thought I would employ a little steganography. If I created 100 empty folders, placing the real files in one undisclosed one she would have a 1% chance of guessing and would probably give up quickly. She could just look at the file size, but I highly doubt she would ever think of that. Anyone know how I can create a whole bunch of folders, I don't want to do it by hand. A simple executable script would be very helpful (e.g. just insert how many folders you want and where). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bash then this will work:

```
for (( i=0; i<100; i++ )); do mkdir junk$i; done
```

It will create 100 directories named junk0 thru junk99.  You can change junk to anything you like.  If you want to get fancy you could read "man random" and figure out how to use random numbers rather than consecutive numbers.